# Django IPython sqlite complains about naive datetime

Tags: django, ipython, pytz

I have a new project in Django 1.4, using sqlite db. Also using django_extenstions' shell_plus with no problems.

When I installed IPython, both `shell` and `shell_plus` started to complain about:

```
/path/to/my/virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py:50:
RuntimeWarning: SQLite received a naive datetime (2012-07-29 13:15:45.229464) while time zone support is active.
```

It seems IPython itself uses unaware datetimes. How can this be fixed?

**EDIT:**

I don't want to disable Django's timezone support.

Comment: @PeterStahl true, it's not a real problem, as long as I don't create datetimes from shell and save them to Django models, and also do that at the "uncertain" time of the year probably close to daylight saving changes, etc. etc... :) And even so, Django would probably drop a warning. But still... Well, it doesn't look nice! :))

Comment: @PeterStahl maybe write that as answer...

Comment: See https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/19738 for Django's deliberations on what to do about this. So far no palatable solution has been presented.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I put this in my local_settings.py:

```
#ignore the following error when using ipython:
#/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py:50: RuntimeWarning:
#SQLite received a naive datetime (2012-11-02 11:20:15.156506) while time zone support is active.

import warnings
import exceptions
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category=exceptions.RuntimeWarning, module='django.db.backends.sqlite3.base', lineno=53)
```

Comment: Great, it works perfectly! Just to be a bit more precise about where to put this code: It is enough to put it in your `settings.py` file of your Django project. You don't need to create another file named `local_settings.py` for that.

Comment: I had to modify this a bit to warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category=exceptions.RuntimeWarning, module='django.db.backends.sqlite3.base', lineno=53)

Comment: It's very important to be aware that by doing this you are exposing yourself to possible data corruption. If you write code that saves naive datetimes to your SQLite database via raw SQL queries, with this "fix" in place Django will no longer be able to warn you about that.

Comment: "There's an iceberg straight ahead!"... "Silence that man and his posterity!"

Comment: . . . `lineno=57` for Django 1.8

Answer (score 12):

I have the same issue but I don't think that it's really a problem. IPython seems to use naive datetimes internally and Django just warns about it. Django always sends this warning when you turn on timezone support and whenever it detects a naive datetime. On my machine, this warning only appears when I start or close IPython. This warning does not influence your work with IPython in any way. So you can safely create aware datetimes normally inside IPython and also save them to your database. In order to get rid of that warning, you probably would have to work on IPython's internals.

When working with aware datetimes in general, I strongly recommend to use [pytz](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/) for this purpose.

Comment: I think honestly the best option available is this one; a.k.a. "just live with it."

Answer (score -3):

modify settings.py, set USE_TZ to False would solve this problem.

Comment: Yeah, but I wish to use the timezone support :)

Comment: -1. This does not solve the problem but just circumvents it by deactivating the useful and important timezone setting of Django. As of version 1.4, it's not recommended to use naive datetimes. Always use aware datetimes if you can. This will prevent you from a lot of problems later on. Also, this warning message doesn't influence IPython's behavior in any way, so it doesn't make sense to deactivate the timezone support.